# How to create a dialog box having multiple types of lists in android?

Tags: android, dialog

I want to create a dialog box which contains a simple list having 2 choices. But I also want to add a single check-box entry in the bottom. Here is the code.

```
    final String s1 = "item 1";
    final String s2 = "item 2";
    final CharSequence[] items = { s1, s2 };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

if (items[item].toString().equalsIgnoreCase(s1)) {
                item1selected();

            } else if (items[item].toString().equalsIgnoreCase(s2)) {
                item2selected();
            }
        }
    }).create();
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.select_dialog_item,
                    new boolean[]{false},
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton,
                                boolean isChecked) {

                            preferences.edit().putBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_entry), isChecked).commit();
                        }
                    }).create();
builder.show();
```

Here, only the check-box item is shown.

Comment: Create one layout and hold each item in your layout than set it in alert dialog using setView() method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine the two.

setMultiChoiceItems is defined as:

```
public Builder setMultiChoiceItems(int itemsId, boolean[] checkedItems, 
            final OnMultiChoiceClickListener listener) {
        P.mItems = P.mContext.getResources().getTextArray(itemsId);
        P.mOnCheckboxClickListener = listener;
        P.mCheckedItems = checkedItems;
        P.mIsMultiChoice = true;
        return this;
    }
```

which resets the items set before.

```
public Builder setItems(CharSequence[] items, final OnClickListener listener) {
        P.mItems = items;
        P.mOnClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }
```

The way to do what you are trying is to use a custom view in your dialog [1] or use the mergeadapter[1] and combine the different lists to one adapter and set it to the alertdialog using setAdapter.

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setView(android.view.View, int, int, int, int)

[2] https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge